# Unable to save form data to database and go to specific page based on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a fake travel website for a project, and I have the basic webpages, and form laid out. I know how to redirect the page based on the selection from the dropdown menu, and I sort of know how to save the form options to my local database, but I can't figure out how to do both. I can either save the data and it redirects to the php that inserts the data into the database, or go to another page without saving the database. Because of this, there are two submit buttons-one that can submit the data, the other leads to another page.

```html
<?php 
  
 session_start();

 if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
  header('location: login.php');
 }

 if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  session_unset(); 
  session_destroy();
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
 }

//When user logged-in
$_SESSION['user_id']="logged_in_user_id";

//When you need to insert
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];

// connect to database
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', 'registration');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// receive all input values from the form
        $Deapart_Place = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Deapart_Place']);
  $Arive_Place = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Arive_Place']);
  $Leave_Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Leave_Date']);
  $Return_Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Return_Date']);
     $Adults = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Adults']);
     $Children = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Children']);

// Insert Data into Trip_Plan Table

 $query= "INSERT INTO Trip_plan (Deapart_Place, Arive_Place, Leave_Date, Return_Date, Adults, Children)
   VALUES ('.$Deapart_Place.', '$Arive_Place', '$Leave_Date', '$Return_Date', '$Adults', '$Children')";
   mysqli_query($db, $query);
 

}

?>
```

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var popupDiv = document.getElementById("popup_bg");

function openPopupMenu() {
  popupDiv.style.display = "block";
}

function closePopupMenu() {
  popupDiv.style.display = "none";

}

function gotosite() {
  window.location = document.getElementById("menu").value; // JQuery:  $("#menu").val();
}

<
/script> 
<!-- End Script for Popup Menu -->
```

```css
@charset 'UTF-8';
html,
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* //border: 1px solid red; */
}

body {
  background-image: url(../images/Thai.jpg);
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  /* padding: 2em; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

nav {
  opacity: 1.10;
  position: relative;
  display: block !important;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.login {
  opacity: 1.10;
  position: static;
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  clear: right;
}

.login a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}


/*    Navigation  */

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*font-size: 20px;
 border-right: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4); */
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 560;
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
  color: #343144;
  background: #fff;
  height: 30vw;
  padding: 9em 6em 5em;
}

.compass {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}


/*  End Navigation  */


/*    Account Dropdown Button  */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 560;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/*  End of Account Dropdown Button  */


/*    Body Grid Types  */

.div1 {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 350px;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.welcome {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}


/*   End Body Grid Types  */


/* PopUp Style  */

#popup_bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#popup_main_div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #89B1E5;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  top: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#close_popup_div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

#close_button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#popup_button {
  position: static;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* End of PopUp Style  */


/* Form Style */

form {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 105px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.search {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 560;
  margin-left: 220px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 204px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1170b9;
  border: 1px solid #1170b9;
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
}

.form {}

.img {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.backoftable {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  opacity: 1.10;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: 610px;
  height: 600px;
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: auto;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 160px;
}

select {
  width: 150px;
}

tr,
td {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 560;
  color: aliceblue;
}

th {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 560;
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<?php 

 session_start(); 

include('insert.php');


 if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
  header('location: login.php');
 }

 if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  session_unset(); 
  session_destroy();
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
 }

//When user logged-in
$_SESSION['user_id']="logged_in_user_id";

//When you need to insert
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Main_Stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Travel_Style.css">
  <link rel="script" href="javascript/Date.js">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body class="backdrop">

  <!--NAVIGATION BAR -->

  <header>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="index.php">Destinations</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="">Packages</a></li>
        <li class="menu">
          <a href="">
            <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>Hello<strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong>
            <?php endif ?>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img class="compass" src="images/compass-icon.png" width="45" height="45" alt="" />
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Acount</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content"> <a href="#">My Plan</a> <a href="login.php?logout='1'">Log Out</a> </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="images/sea.jpg" width="400" height="600" alt="" box-shadow="0px 0px 130px rgba(0,0,0,.85)" />
  </div>

  <!--END OF NAVIGATION BAR -->


  <div class="backoftable">

    <table>
      <!-- Fourm Heading -->
      <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" action="insert.php" />


        <th colspan="2" style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <p style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 20px;font-size: 25;">Book Your Trip and Select Your Package </p>
        </th>
        <!-- End of Fourm Heading -->
        <tr>
          <th>
            <label for="Departing From">Departing From:</label><br>
          </th>
          <th>


            <label for="Arriving To">Arriving To:</label>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Deaprting From-->
        <td>
          <select name="Deapart_Place">
<option value="Bradley International Airport">Bradley International Airport | Windsor Locks, CT</option>
<option value="Hartford–Brainard Airport">Hartford–Brainard Airport | Hartford, CT</option>
<option value="Westchester County Airport">Westchester County Airport | White Plains, NY</option>
<option value="Sikorsky Memorial Airport" >Sikorsky Memorial Airport | Stratford, CT</option>
<option value="John F. Kennedy International Airport">JFK International Airport | Queens, NY</option>
</select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <!-- Arriving to-->

          <select id="menu">
<option value="" >Choose Arriving Airport...</option>
<option value="California_Info.php">Los Angeles International Airport | Los Angeles, CA</option>
<option value="California_Info.php">San Francisco International Airport | San Francisco, CA</option>
<option value="Florida_Info.php">Orlando International Airport | Orlando, FL</option>
<option value="Florida_Info.php">Florida Keys Marathon Airport | Marathon, FL</option>
<option value="Louisiana_Info.php">LANO International Airport | Kenner, LA</option>
<option value="Louisiana_Info.php">Lakefront Airport | New Orleans, LA</option>
</select>

          <tr>
            <th>
              <label for="Departure">Departure Date:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <label for="Return2">Return Date:</label><br>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <td><input type="date" id="mydate" required min="{{today}}"></td>
          <td><input type="date"></td>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <lable for="Number of Adults">Adults</lable>
              <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
            </td>
            <td>
              <lable for="Number of Children">Children</lable>
              <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
            </td>
          </tr>
      </form>
    </table>
    <input class="search" type="submit" name="submit" onClick="gotosite()" value="submit">
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Is there I way that I can save the data and go a specific page based on the dropdown selection. I am still fairly new to php , and javascript, so my code might not be the neatest.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

Create a form element like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/save.php">
  <select name="urls[]">
    <option value="urlValue">
  </select>
</form>
```

Click on a button to send to the action script(save.php) where you can
do whatever is necessary - save to database etc. and then use the 
HTTP header directive header(Here place the submitted value from the dropdown).

Hope I explained that clear enough! Good luck!